# adding static() to urlpatterns only work by appending to the list

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-urls

I'm pretty sure there is a duplicate lying around, but couldn't find it.

When declaring a `urlpatterns` in **urls.py** on dev, I use the following successfully:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # some routes
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Which understandably, works.

But if I try the following:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # some routes,
    static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
]
```

django server dies complaining:

> `?: (urls.E004) Your URL pattern [<URLPattern '^static\/(?P<path>.*)$'>] is invalid. Ensure that urlpatterns is a list of path() and/or re_path() instances.`

Why aren't the two definitions equivalent? The return of `static()` should be the same:

```
return [
    re_path(r'^%s(?P<path>.*)$' % re.escape(prefix.lstrip('/')), view, kwargs=kwargs),
]
```

And thus valid, but only works if I concatenate the element to the list instead of defining it in the list directly.

Why one method works but not the other?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Well the static function does *not* return a single `url`, so you can not add it as a *single* element to the list. By using `+=`, you actually append all the *elements* of the result of the `static` call to the list.

Recent versions of Python however have special syntax to include an iterable in a list by using the asterisk (`*`), so it can still be done with:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # some routes,
    *static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
]
```